# Can one Daven with the 'wrong' pronunciation?

Tags: tefilla, minhag, pronunciation

Can one Daven (as the chazan or by himself) using a different pronunciation of letters / vowels than his minhag?

For example, pronouncing a  תּ and a ת (with and without a dagesh) the same, instead of his minhag of differentiating, or saying a Patach and a kamatz differently, instead of his minhag of not differentiating between them.

Note that I don't mean that he would change his minhag. Just temporarily pronounce them according to a different minhag.

Comment: Consider tosfot megillah 24b

Comment: I think I once heard an opinion that said that if you are leading the davening for a minyan which normally has a specific pronounciation that is different to yours, you should use their pronounciation

Comment: For the most part, you can daven in English, so it wouldn't be worse than that. There are some restrictions which may apply to davening in a language other than Hebrew though, so the question is still relevant.

Comment: @DoubleAA that seems to be in a case where we know that the pronunciation of the chazan is wrong. Would it hold true if we don't?

Comment: @Loani Classically, that is the only kind of case.

Comment: @DoubleAA true. Would it hold true if we don't know whether the proposed pronunciation *is* correct? Because then, even if the chazan is wrong, if the other pronunciation is wrong as well, should/ can he change minhag?

Comment: @Loani Classically, a doubt about proper pronunciation was never considered. People knew they weren't pronouncing things correctly and didn't pretend that having learned broken Hebrew from a parent who lived in whatever country remedied that. There are very few aspects of Hebrew pronunciation that there is any major doubt about. When anyone gets up to daven they should pronounce Hebrew as best they can, and if it isn't good enough (classically, mixing up alef and ayin) then they shouldn't be allowed to lead.

Comment: @DoubleAA Right I understand that. My question is in a case where we no longer know the correct pronunciation, and either one might be correct, like pronouncing a tzeirei as 'ei' vs. 'eh' - since changing might not be of any benefit, and according to the chazans mesora is detrimental, my svara was he shouldn't change his minhag (or, if the shul tells him to - he shouldn't be chazan).

Answer (score 1):

When we made aliyah, I asked our new local Rav about how I should pronounce words when I daven, especially since I planned on davening from the amud. (In the U.S. I davened nusach Ashkanaz with an Ashkanazi pronunciation.) Should I change?
He answered, "Don't change. Daven the way you've been davening. If you change you're bound to pronounce words wrong. I don't think there will be any shules in Israel who will care about your pronunciation."

Comment: Can you elaborate how this answers the question? Note, the title of the question doesn't quite capture the question's essence, the body of the question is more specific