# Can one pray with different nusach pronunciations

Tags: halacha, tefilla, pronunciation

Can I pray with switching off between how different nusachim pronounce different words? The most obvious is example is Taf vs Saf- let’s say I’m saying Shema, am I allowed to say some words with the Taf and some with the Saf? Or just it all be the same consistent pronunciation? And if so, if one accidentally intermixed, is he not yotzei?

Comment: I don't have the sources on me, but I've seen that it's problematic to mix pronunciations.

Comment: Related: "[Can one Daven with the 'wrong' pronunciation?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/138148/1368)"

Comment: https://chabadlibrary.org/books/admur/ig/20/7677.htm

Comment: Clearly this isn't the right way to say shema according to either tradition. It's fine to ask if it still works after the fact, but I don't understand how anyone could think this is find to do on purpose

Comment: @DoubleAA it’s not as if I’m davka going out of my way to do it, but I grew up half Ashki half Sefardi and usually speak the Sefardi way when I talk aloud because I grew up around Sefardis, but I pray with the ashkenaz pronunciation, but a lot of times they’ll accidentally interchange

Comment: Your personal situation is irrelevant. I'm just discussing the question posted.